# How to remove unselect event after select magento 2 configurable product

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.4

I have Magento 2(2.2.4) website, where I have 3 options(simple product) for a configurable product. I see Magento 2 behavior allow the user to unselect the option after selection.

So I want to remove the unselect event after selecting any option. The user should be able to use another option but should not be able to unselect the selected option.

Note: I am not a developer, so when you reply request you to reply with exact file path where to edit. That will really help me to fix my issue.

Thanks in Advance!!